# Identify if there is a repetition per row in Python

Tags: python, sequence

I am pretty new to Python.

I am trying to identify if an item is repeated or not in a column.

If I have:

```
x = [a, b, c, d, d, d, e, f, f]
```

I would like to get:

```
rep = [no, no, no, no, yes, yes, no, no, yes]
```

Can I do this with a `for` loop? Or maybe apply a function?
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a set to keep track of what you've seen, and append conditions based on if an element is in the set:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f']
is_dupes = []
seen = set()

for e in x:
    if e in seen:
        is_dupes.append('yes')
    else:
        is_dupes.append('no')
        seen.add(e)

is_dupes
# ['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a reproducible object, say

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'f']
```

you could use [list-comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and do

```
>>> [x[:i+1].count(el)>1 for i,el in enumerate(x)]
[False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
```

And if you want to turn booleans into yes/no, simply do

```
>>> ['yes' if x[:i+1].count(el)>1 else 'no' for i,el in enumerate(x)]
['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']
```

Comment: I did a mistake. Here's the real error: `KeyError: 'Level bor must be same as name (None)'`. `bor` is one iof the items in the sequence. I am doing: 'datahitword['misread'] = [datahitword['clean_word'][:i + 1].count(el) > 1 for i, el in enumerate(datahitword['clean_word'])]`

Comment: @DanielVargas. How? Which error? I have tested my example with *python 2.7 and 3.6.*

Comment: I used @Psidom answer. But I still want to explore yours, is always good to have multiple strategies. I tried: `dup = []
dup = [datahitword['clean_word'][:i + 1].count(el) > 1 for i, el in enumerate(datahitword['clean_word'])]`, and got: `KeyError: 'Level bor must be same as name (None)'`

Comment: @DanielVargas I am afraid, given *what you asked*, I answered your question, right ? In the Community interest, it may be a good idea to post your issue as a new question. If you encounter this problem, it is very likely that others will as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, all you have to do is iterate over consecutive pairs of items in the list and check if the two in each pair are equal. There's a handy function you can use to do this called `pairwise()`, whose implementation is given in the [itertools package documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), or you can just use it directly from the [more-itertools library](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/). You'd use it like this:

```
for item1, item2 in pairwise(rep):
    # choose yes or no
```

I'd actually recommend putting this in a list comprehension, that way you build up the results into a list right from the beginning.

```
[ (choose yes or no) for item1, item2 in pairwise(rep)]
```

Then you will have to stick an extra `'no'` on the front because the first element has nothing before it to be equal to.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL of this homework question, please?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def y_or_n(bool):
    return 'yes' if bool else 'no'


def rep(xs):
    seen = set()
    ret = []
    for x in xs:
        ret.append(y_or_n(x in seen))
        seen.add(x)
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(rep('a b c d d d e f f'.split()))
```

Comment: it is not a homework, I am working on a dataset which has needed a lot of manipulation.